# Google compute engine - API to get the total instance cost

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is there any API I can use to get the total cost of a VM instance in Google compute?

The usage scenario is like this:

- Server starts
- Runs for some Hours / Days
- Gets shut down
- For reporting purposes, we get the cost of the server and save it in our DB

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Google has a system for exporting billing information each day in a csv/json file to a storage bucket.

http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ca/2013/12/ow-get-programmatic-access-to-your-billing-data-with-new-billing-api.html

Comment: Yeah, that is indeed a way, thanks for posting it. But it's not an API call. I am more interested in an API call that I can make whenever I need the data, instead of having to wait until the day lapses to get it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google does not have such an API.